# Flutter iOS Push Notification

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

in my Project, I want to display custom notifications to the user with Awesome Notification `awesome_notifications`

I have configured my Firebase and Yes, I do receive Push Notifications on my iPhone, I have tested it working.

My issue is with the Payload request used to send the push notification

when I set my message with the **notification object** in the payload, the message will be delivered and display on the iPhone but once I remove the **notification object**, no message is been displayed on the iPhone but yes the message was delivered,

**Example A**

```
{
    "registration_ids":[
        "XXXEW23232332323232332oES-xeLNriKi_kds19eB6p9liZfl7pkJ8WWHh45G8VwJLH6-DK3bd7lRCGWQ_"
    ],
    "notification":{
        "title":"Title Push 2",
        "body":"test message body",
        "android_channel_id":"push_notification_demo",
        "sound":true,
        "":""
    },
    "data":{
       "fromName": "Nosa",
        "messageType": "VOICE_CALL",
        "message":  "What do you think",
        "fromUserId":  "09034286339"
    }
}
```

**Example B**

```
{
    "registration_ids":[
         "XXXEW23232332323232332oES-xeLNriKi_kds19eB6p9liZfl7pkJ8WWHh45G8VwJLH6-DK3bd7lRCGWQ_"
    ],
   
    "data":{
       "fromName": "Nosa",
        "messageType": "VOICE_CALL",
        "message":  "What do you think",
        "fromUserId":  "09034286339"
    }
}
```

> From the Two sample codes, Example A will be delivered and displayed
> on the iPhone but Example B will only be delivered but does not
> displayed on the iPhone

I'm using Awesome notification to handle the Notification, I'm only interested in the data object sent because, in my project, I'm handling incoming phone calls so I don't want a default Notification, and yes, I have also added the `aps` object to my code, yet no message is displaying on the iPhone device.

please, how can I resolve this?